# MPI C - Root node receives more than one arrays

Tags: c, mpi

Each slave will send an array **num** with length **len** to root node. How will I be able to store all these array in 2D array?

```
if (world_rank == root) {
    for(i=1; i<world_size;i++) {
      // clueless what to do 
    }
    MPI_Waitall(world_size-1, &rcv_request[1], &status[1]);  
}
else {
    MPI_Isend(num, len, MPI_FLOAT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_request[i]);
    MPI_Wait(&send_request[1], &status[1]);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending distributed chunks of a 2D array to the root process in MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530648/sending-distributed-chunks-of-a-2d-array-to-the-root-process-in-mpi?rq=1)